# Should the search options page make it more clear that the Ninja syntax applies only to the top right search box?

Tags: feature-request, search, user-interface, usability

I just <strike>wasted</strike> spent the last 30 minutes wondering why the *Advanced Super Ninja Search Options* weren't working for me.

It turns out that these options **only** work in the top right search box and not the three `Search Stack Overflow With Google|Bing|DuckDuckGo` search boxes on the same page.

Whilst the opening paragraph does say:

> To search, type in the box at the top right of every page and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The presence of the three search engine search boxes on that page do implicitly suggest the Ninja options will work there too. I do realise that if you look closely at the Google results it does say that *user:419 was dropped from your search*, but you have to look closely.

Perhaps some additional text would be useful to make it abundantly clear that the Ninja search options will only work with the top right search box?